# How to Change Wordpress Upload Folder Programmatically?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, upload, dir

I've got a custom theme that I've created an upload button where I call the Wordpress Uploader when these buttons are pressed.  Something like this:

```
jQuery('#ahng_blog_upload_button').click(function() { 
    formfield = jQuery('#ahng_blog_upload_image').attr('name');
    tb_show('Upload or Select Photo and Click on "Insert into Post"', 'media-upload.php?type=audio&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
});
```

Right now, in my `functions.php` folder, I've set where I'd like the files to Upload (`http://website.com/wp-content/uploads`) but I want to change the Upload location depending on which button is pressed.

For example, when the *'Upload Picture'* button is pressed, change the upload folder to **`images`** (`http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/images`), and when the *'Upload MP3'* button is pressed, change the upload folder to **`audio`** (`http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/audio`).

I know I can upload everything to the default folder which I mentioned previously, but it's easier to sort through later if I need to look for a specific file using ftp.

Is there a way to do that using jquery and ajax and calling a php file that doesn't really return anything but makes changes to the Upload Dir in wordpress?  Or any other way?

Comment: I have the same question. Anybody?!

Answer (score 4):

The method I use is based in pure WordPress hooks, no jQuery or Ajax involved.

And I really don't know what buttons you are referring to... There's been some time since the only button is "Upload Media". Unless you are using customized ones.

This [WordPress StackExchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53895/12615) has other filtering possibilities. Bellow is that code adjusted to filter the uploads by media type.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse_25894_handle_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse_25894_handle_upload');

function wpse_25894_handle_upload_prefilter( $file )
{
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

function wpse_25894_handle_upload( $fileinfo )
{
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir($path)
{   
    // Determines if uploading from inside a post/page/cpt
    // If not, default Upload folder is used
    $use_default_dir = (
            isset($_REQUEST['post_id'] ) 
            && $_REQUEST['post_id'] == 0 
            ) 
            ? true : false; 

    if( !empty( $path['error'] ) || $use_default_dir )
        return $path; //error or uploading not from a post/page/cpt 

     // Save uploads in FILETYPE based folders. When using this method, 
     // you may want to change the check for $use_default_dir
     $extension = substr( strrchr( $_POST['name'], '.' ), 1 );

     switch( $extension )
     {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            $customdir = '/images';
            break;

        case 'mp4':
        case 'm4v':
            $customdir = '/videos';
            break;

        case 'txt':
        case 'doc':
        case 'pdf':
            $customdir = '/documents';
            break;

        default:
            $customdir = '/others';
            break;
     }

    //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); 
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);  

    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  

    return $path;
}
```